# Kotlin android extensions, packages cannot be imported

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-gradle-plugin, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I installed the latest Kotlin android extensions plugin (version 1.0.0-beta-1103) and added the classpath to my Gradle dependencies. It compiles but I am still unable to import a package inside my android fragment.

Here is the relevant portion of the Gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.0-beta-1103'
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:1.0.0-beta-1103"
    }

}
```

Here is the import statement that is failing. My IDE states shows the error "Packages cannot be imported"

```java
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.fragment_new_movie.view
```

Comment: Please post code as text next time, not as images.

Comment: Will do, not sure why I didn't :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to specify what view you want or at least put a wildcard.

For example:

```
import view.*
```

or

```
import view.some_specific_view
```

Answer (score 0):

A more correct answer is:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.fragment_new_movie.*
```

The above answer is somewhat correct but lacking the complete import might cause some confusion.

An alternative:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.fragment_new_movie.view.*
```